# how to Converting JSON into Codable in swift 4.2?

Tags: json, swift, codable

I am using Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.2. When i try to convert JSON response  into Codable class it gives an error that `Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a string/data instead.`

My Actual JSON response  is Like this from API .

```
{
    "d": "[{\"Data\":{\"mcustomer\":[{\"slno\":1000000040.0,\"fstname\":null}]},\"Status\":true}]"
}
```

My Model is Like this

```
class MainData: Codable{

    var d: [SubData]

}

class SubData : Codable {


    var Data : Customer

    var Status : Bool?

}


class Customer : Codable {

    var mcustomer : [Detail]

}


class Detail : Codable {

    var slno : Double?

    var fstname : String?

}
```

And I am Decode this Model using JSONDecoder()

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

let deco = try decoder.decode(MainData.self, from: data)
```

but, I am unable to Decode this Json into My Model.

Answer (score 1):

Your API is wrong. You array in json shouldn't have quotation marks around it. Otherwise you're declaring that value for key `"d"` is string

<strike>`"[...]"`</strike>

`[...]`

---

Suggestions:

- Variables and constants should start with small capital letter. Otherwise for example your `Data` property would cause confusion with `Data` type. For renaming it while decoding you can use `CodingKeys`
- If you don't need to encode your model, you can just implement `Decodable` protocol
- You can use `struct` instead of `class` for your model

Comment: If you copy that response and check it  in this url then you get exact output you want https://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html#ad-output

Comment: I don't understand Whether Json response is wrong or My Model is wrong . i am trying to parse this json from last 2 days, but i'm not able to parse .

Answer (score 0):

The top-level JSON object is a dictionary with the key "d" and a *string* value, representing another JSON object (sometimes called "nested JSON"). If the server API cannot be changed then the decoding must be done in two steps:

- Decode the top-level dictionary.
- Decode the JSON object from the string obtained in step one.

Together with Robert's advice about naming, `CodingKeys` and using  `struct`s it would look like this:

```
struct MainData: Codable {
    let d: String
}

struct SubData : Codable {
    let data : Customer
    let status : Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data = "Data"
        case status = "Status"
    }
}

struct Customer : Codable {
    let mcustomer : [Detail]
}

struct Detail : Codable {
    let slno : Double
    let fstname : String?
}

do {
    let mainData = try JSONDecoder().decode(MainData.self, from: data)
    let subData = try JSONDecoder().decode([SubData].self, from: Data(mainData.d.utf8))

    print(subData)

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thaks Bro . Finally i Parse my response in Model and Suggesting me that use CodingKeys Keys

Answer (score 0):

For your solution to work, the JSON reponse has to be following format

```
let json = """
  {
  "d": [
    {
      "Data": {
        "mcustomer": [
          {
            "slno": 1000000040,
            "fstname": null
          }
        ]
      },
      "Status": true
    }
  ]
}
"""
```

But, as you can see, the JSON response you are getting is quite different than you are expecting. Either you need to ask to change the response or you need to change your model.